# Refill tube in toilet tank

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I was changing out the flapper and accidentally knocked loose the refill tube.  I see online they typically have clips to secure them in place.  In my case, it looks like there is a small hole that the tube goes in.  It also looks like there was some sort of glue applied at some point.

I’ve put the tube back in the small hole, I’m just not sure how secure it is.  Is there a particular sealant/glue I should get to hold it in place or should I just look for a clip?

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCaFS.jpg)

[image]

Comment: They are typically not under any pressure.  If it just fits well you should be fine.

Comment: Leave it like that. If it slips out it will do no damage, but just won't top off the bowl after each flush. - Check it every day or so for a couple weeks.